# Need to call multiple EJBs based on the input string

Tags: java, design-patterns, ejb-3.1

I have a pojo class where in I have to call multiple ejbs based on the input string. For example , if the input is a x, I have to call XServiceBean, and if it is Y, I have to call YServiceBean. 
I am planning to parameterise the input string x and the respective service bean in the database or xml.  I do not want to put multiple if conditions or switch cases to call the service bean based on the input string.

Is there any simple pattern that i can use to achieve this. would be helpful if you can give some example
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main class where you can run as java for testing purpose

```
package stack;

public class ServiceInit
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       new ServiceInit();
   }

   public ServiceInit()
   {
       ServiceBeanInterface xbean = ServiceFactory.getInstance().getServiceBean("X");

       xbean.callService();

       ServiceBeanInterface ybean = ServiceFactory.getInstance().getServiceBean("Y");

       ybean.callService();
   }
}
```

Service Factory which returns the bean that you want to call

```
package stack;

public class ServiceFactory
{

/*
 * you can do it with factory and class reflection if the input is always the prefix for the service bean. 
 */
private static ServiceFactory instance;

// the package name where your service beans are
private final String serviceBeanPackage = "stack.";

private ServiceFactory()
{

}

public static ServiceFactory getInstance()
{
    if (instance == null)
    {
        instance = new ServiceFactory();
    }
    return instance;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public ServiceBeanInterface getServiceBean(String prefix)
{
    ServiceBeanInterface serviceBean = null;
    try
    {

        Class<ServiceBeanInterface> bean = (Class<ServiceBeanInterface>) Class
                .forName(serviceBeanPackage + prefix + "ServiceBean");

        serviceBean = bean.newInstance();
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return serviceBean;

}

}
```

The interface which is implemented by your service classes

```
package stack;

public interface ServiceBeanInterface
{
    void callService();
}
```

XServiceBean class

```
package stack;

public class XServiceBean implements ServiceBeanInterface
{

@Override
public void callService()
{
    System.out.println("I am X");
}

}
```

YServiceBean class

```
package stack;

public class YServiceBean implements ServiceBeanInterface
{

   @Override
   public void callService()
   {
       System.out.println("I am Y");
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for Ur suggestion.